# Vuforia - How to save a file with target name?

Tags: android, vuforia

I need get target name for my app when detected my target, I'm trying like this:
But don't work. Any ideas?
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I searched and find the solution :)

How to save:

[Saving to SD card as text file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19853401/android-saving-to-sd-card-as-text-file)

permission:

[Conflict between vuforia plugin and prime31 facebook plugin for android on unity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19940179/conflict-between-vuforia-plugin-and-prime31-facebook-plugin-for-android-on-unity)

Put permession  in AndroidManifest.xml